# Unlist a list of inputs from shiny dynamic UI into data frame

Tags: r, shiny

Am newbie to Shiny, please help.
I managed to create dynamic input placeholder on user's clicking action button and render the output in the most simple way (as list).

However, I cannot unlist the output (in a list format) into data frame in order to :

1. Filter the choices for the next selections
2. Do calculations and filtering later.

My input looks like below:

```
 FilmProducer         Series Episode
1       Amazon Prime Video       Mirzapur    Ep 1
2       Amazon Prime Video       Mirzapur    Ep 2
3       Amazon Prime Video       Mirzapur    Ep 3
4       Amazon Prime Video       Mirzapur    Ep 4
5       Amazon Prime Video       The Boys    Ep 1
6       Amazon Prime Video       The Boys    Ep 2
7       Amazon Prime Video       The Boys    Ep 3
8       Amazon Prime Video       The Boys    Ep 4
9  The Walt Disney Company       AndiMack    Ep 1
10 The Walt Disney Company       AndiMack    Ep 2
11 The Walt Disney Company Lizzie McGuire    Ep 1
12 The Walt Disney Company Lizzie McGuire    Ep 2
13 The Walt Disney Company Lizzie McGuire    Ep 3
```

And as a `dput`:

```
structure(list(FilmProducer = c("Amazon Prime Video", "Amazon Prime Video", 
"Amazon Prime Video", "Amazon Prime Video", "Amazon Prime Video", 
"Amazon Prime Video", "Amazon Prime Video", "Amazon Prime Video", 
"The Walt Disney Company", "The Walt Disney Company", "The Walt Disney Company", 
"The Walt Disney Company", "The Walt Disney Company"), Series = c("Mirzapur", 
"Mirzapur", "Mirzapur", "Mirzapur", "The Boys", "The Boys", "The Boys", 
"The Boys", "AndiMack", "AndiMack", "Lizzie McGuire", "Lizzie McGuire", 
"Lizzie McGuire"), Episode = c("Ep 1", "Ep 2", "Ep 3", "Ep 4", 
"Ep 1", "Ep 2", "Ep 3", "Ep 4", "Ep 1", "Ep 2", "Ep 1", "Ep 2", 
"Ep 3")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", "2", "3", 
"4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13"))
```

The way I want the output in data frame format follows the desired workflow below:

After the first selection:

```
 FilmProducer         Series Episode
Amazon Prime Video       Mirzapur    Ep 1
Amazon Prime Video       Mirzapur    Ep 2
Amazon Prime Video       Mirzapur    Ep 3
```

I want the next selection to be filtered based on leftover data:

```
 FilmProducer         Series Episode
Amazon Prime Video       Mirzapur    Ep 4
Amazon Prime Video       The Boys    Ep 1
Amazon Prime Video       The Boys    Ep 2
Amazon Prime Video       The Boys    Ep 3
Amazon Prime Video       The Boys    Ep 4
The Walt Disney Company       AndiMack    Ep 1
The Walt Disney Company       AndiMack    Ep 2
The Walt Disney Company Lizzie McGuire    Ep 1
The Walt Disney Company Lizzie McGuire    Ep 2
The Walt Disney Company Lizzie McGuire    Ep 3
```

After second selection:

```
 FilmProducer         Series Episode
Amazon Prime Video       The Boys    Ep 4
The Walt Disney Company       AndiMack    Ep 1
The Walt Disney Company       AndiMack    Ep 2
```

I want the output to be in a data frame with the 'selectionID' in the first column

```
FilmProducer               Series          Episode        selectionID
Amazon Prime Video         Mirzapur        Ep 1           1
Amazon Prime Video         Mirzapur        Ep 2           1
Amazon Prime Video         Mirzapur        Ep 3           1
Amazon Prime Video         The Boys        Ep 4           2
The Walt Disney Company    AndiMack        Ep 1           2
The Walt Disney Company    AndiMack        Ep 2           2
```

My code is below (I borrowed some lines from another post from stackoverflow too):

```
library(tidyr)
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)
row_ui <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  fluidRow(
    column(2, textInput(ns("SelectionID"), label = "Enter the name of your selection:")),
    column(2, uiOutput(ns("FilmProducer"))),
    column(2, uiOutput(ns("Series"))),
    column(2, uiOutput(ns("Episode")))
  )
}


setwd("~")
getwd()
FilmOption <- read.csv("~SampleforStackOverflow.csv", header=T, encoding = "UTF-8")
FilmOption <- rename(FilmOption,"FilmProducer" = "X.U.FEFF.FilmProducer")

row_server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$FilmProducer <- renderUI({
    ns <- session$ns
    type <- req(input$SelectionID)
    if(!is.null(type)) {
      selectInput(ns("FilmProducer"),"Choose the Film Producer:",choices = c("Amazon Prime Video","The Walt Disney Company"), selected = NULL) 
    } 
  })
  
  output$Series <- renderUI({
    ns <- session$ns
    type <- req(input$SelectionID)
    if(!is.null(type)) {
      selectInput(ns("Series"),"Choose the Series name:",choices = NULL, multiple = TRUE, selected = NULL)
    }
  }
  )
  
  observeEvent(input$FilmProducer, {
    ProducerList <- FilmOption %>% 
      filter(FilmProducer == input$FilmProducer) %>% 
      select(Series) %>% distinct() %>% arrange(Series)
    ProducerList <- rbind(ProducerList,"")
    ProducerList[2:nrow(ProducerList),] <- ProducerList[1:(nrow(ProducerList)-1),]
    ProducerList[1,] <- "Select All"
    if (nrow(ProducerList) == 1) {
      updateSelectInput(session, "Series","Choose the Series name:",
                        choices = as.character(ProducerList))
    }
    else {updateSelectInput(session, "Series","Choose the Series name:",
                            choices = ProducerList)}
  })      
  
  observeEvent(input$Series,{
    if("Select All" %in% input$Series) {
      ProducerList <- FilmOption %>%
        filter(FilmProducer == input$FilmProducer) %>% 
        select(Series) %>% distinct() %>% arrange(Series)
      ProducerList <- rbind(ProducerList,"")
      ProducerList[2:nrow(ProducerList),] <- ProducerList[1:(nrow(ProducerList)-1),]
      ProducerList[1,] <- "Select All"
      selected_choices= ProducerList[-1,]}
    else
      selected_choices=input$Series
    updateSelectInput(session, "Series", "Choose the Series name:", selected = selected_choices)
  })
  
  output$Episode <- renderUI({
    ns <- session$ns
    type <- req(input$SelectionID)
    if(!is.null(type)) {
      selectInput(ns("Episode"),"Choose the Episode:",choices = NULL, multiple = TRUE, selected = NULL)
    } 
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$Series, {
    SeriesList <- FilmOption %>% 
      filter(FilmProducer == input$FilmProducer) %>% 
      filter(Series == input$Series) %>% 
      select(Episode) %>% distinct() %>% arrange(Episode)
    SeriesList <- rbind(SeriesList,"")
    SeriesList[2:nrow(SeriesList),] <- SeriesList[1:(nrow(SeriesList)-1),]
    SeriesList[1,] <- "Select All"
    if (nrow(SeriesList) == 1) {
      updateSelectInput(session, "Episode","Choose the Episode:",
                        choices = as.character(SeriesList))
    }
    else {updateSelectInput(session, "Episode","Choose the Episode:",
                            choices = SeriesList)}
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$Episode, {
    SeriesList <- FilmOption %>% 
      filter(FilmProducer == input$FilmProducer) %>% 
      filter(Series == input$Series) %>% 
      select(Episode) %>% distinct() %>% arrange(Episode)
    SeriesList <- rbind(SeriesList,"")
    SeriesList[2:nrow(SeriesList),] <- SeriesList[1:(nrow(SeriesList)-1),]
    SeriesList[1,] <- "Select All"
    if("Select All" %in% input$Episode) {
      selected_choices= SeriesList[-1,]}
    else
      selected_choices=input$Episode
    updateSelectInput(session, "Episode", "Choose the Episode:", selected = selected_choices)
  })
  

  return(c(reactive({input$FilmProducer}), 
           reactive({input$Series}),
           reactive({input$Episode})
  ))
}


ui <- fluidPage(  
  div(id="placeholder"),
  actionButton("submit", "Add Selection:"),
  verbatimTextOutput("out")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  handler <- reactiveVal(list())
  observeEvent(input$submit, {
    new_id <- paste("row", input$submit, sep = "_")
    insertUI(
      selector = "#placeholder",
      where = "beforeBegin",
      ui = row_ui(new_id)
    )
    handler_list <- isolate(handler())
    new_handler <- callModule(row_server, new_id)
    handler_list <- c(handler_list, new_handler)
    names(handler_list)[length(handler_list)] <- new_id
    handler(handler_list)
  })
  
  output$out <- renderPrint({
    lapply(handler(), function(handle) {
      handle()
    })
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: can u `dput()` your objects here

Comment: I am sorry... Can you elaborate what you mean @PorkChop . The question has a dput(). Here when I pasted it exceeds the number of characters allowed.